# Panels behavior : separation

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have 3 panels on top of each others and 3 buttons. What I want to achieve is with every button click its correspondent panel appears, currently I am using `panel.Visible = true;` and `panel.Visible = false;` but since every element over a panel in a WFA is considered a child of that panel all I get is either they are all visible or they are all invisible.

Q: How to make each panel behave separately?

This is the visibility control code:

```
private void btnHome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panelHome.Visible = true;
    panelContact.Visible = false;
    panelOther.Visible = false;
}

private void btnContact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panelHome.Visible = false;
    panelContact.Visible = true;
    panelOther.Visible = false;
}

private void btnOther_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panelHome.Visible = false;
    panelContact.Visible = false;
    panelOther.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Can't you use a [tabcontrol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: yes sure I can, but in this case panels are needed

Comment: To place a panel __on top__ instead of __nested inside__ another panel you can bring it close and then __use the keyboard__ for thas couple of pixels. But of course you can also do  it in code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is easly solved using the graphical user interface:

> You just need to **carefully** place every panel on top of the previous one until the blue `guidelines` appear.
>
> PS: You need to check 2 guidelines: one vertical (left or right) and one horizontal (top or bottom)

Comment: Probably easier achieved using the "document outline" window

Comment: I think you could use BringToFront() and SendToBack() methods !

Comment: This works, although I prefer using the __keyboard__ or the __align-commands__ @kaj: No.

Comment: why not ? I used it with four panels places on top of each others, then just call BringToFront() to show the wanted panel ! isn't it what the OP asked ?